# How to decide to use どうせ or しょせん?

Tags: usage, nuances

The dictionary translates both どうせ ([WJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9B)) and しょせん ([WJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E6%89%80%E8%A9%AE)) as "anyway / in any case / after all".

But what exactly is the difference in nuance between them?

For example, what is the difference between [this sentence](http://goo.gl/8k6JP):

> 時間はあなたの好きなように過ごせばいい。**しょせん**、あなたの時間なのだから。

and this:

> 時間はあなたの好きなように過ごせばいい。**どうせ**、あなたの時間なのだから。

How do we decide when to use which?

Comment: Also there is とにかく, それより etc.

Comment: どうせ might be a shortened version of どちらにせよ/どうしたって(whichever you take/whatever you do/however you try)/(どっちみち/どのみち?) or something. 所詮[しょせん] means "after all/anyhow(結局/とにかく)" but also sounds to me like せいぜい~~に過ぎない(at most/at best/only...) and I think we often use it as a set phrase of しょせん～～にすぎない. Compared to 結局・とにかく・しょせん, I think どうせ can carry more apathetic or negligent tone, grumbling tone, or criticizing tone. And どうせ sounds to me more conversational than しょせん.

Comment: @Chocolate Btw is there a "more conversational" version of しょせん?

Comment: @Paceriersan, As sawa-san stated in her post, I think しょせん can normally be replaced by どうせ(--am I right?). どうせ sounds to me much more conversational than しょせん.

Comment: @Chocolate But using どうせ, there will be a "grumbling" connotation right? Is there a word that is commonly used in conversation but doesn't have the "grumbling" connotation?

Comment: @Paceriersan, Yes, for example「どうせ私は~~だ」「どうせ~~に決まってる」sound sulky, especially when you talk about yourself I think, sound like implying you know the hearer looks down on you (Like... どうせ私なんか役立たずよ=I know I'm useless/Of course I'm useless.) or you've already given up before trying (Like...どうせ失敗するに決まってる/どうせうまく行きっこないんだ=I know I'll fail anyway/I know it won't work anyway). Actually on some other site someone said "どうせ私はネイティブではありませんので~~" and it sounded odd, because she obviously didn't know that どうせ has a sulky, grumbling or criticizing tone. I might just avoid using the word to avoid sounding...

Comment: (cont.) sulky or grumbling... I can't think of any other casual word that can replace it and that doesn't have a grumbling tone... Maybe I'll use 結局 but it can't always replace どうせ.

Comment: @Chocolate Hmm, so do you mean that 結局 is the best word to replace どう in the sentence "どうせ私はネイティブではありませんので~~", or are there better alternatives?

Comment: @Chocolate Sry, also I was wondering would 所詮 or どうせい be more natural in the sentence: XXあいつらは動物だ、なくなってもかまわない。

Comment: @Paceriersan, I would rather not say どうせ if I said that, like "私はネイティブではありませんので~~".

Comment: @Paceriersan, 「所詮あいつらは動物だ~~」sounds more natural to me. (I think どうせ and 所詮 have a bit different nuances, so they are not always interchangeable. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- どうせ may imply excess or insufficiency.

> どうせ、彼は中学生だ。幼稚園児とけんかすれば勝つだろう。
>   どうせ、彼は中学生だ。大したことはできないだろう。

所詮 usually implies insufficiency　(# indicates pragmmatic anomaly).

> # 所詮、彼は中学生だ。幼稚園児とけんかすれば勝つだろう。
>   　所詮、彼は中学生だ。大したことはできないだろう。

- どうせ implies that **a proposition** has something to do with the context.

> どうせ、掃除する
>   　どうせ、(彼は)中学生だ

所詮 implies that **a property** of something has something to do with the context.

> * 所詮、掃除する
>   　所詮、(彼は)中学生だ

From this, it follows that どうせ, but not 所詮, can be used in conditionals.

> どうせ掃除するなら、丁寧にする。
>   どうせ掃除しても、またすぐに汚れる。
>   * 所詮、掃除するなら、丁寧にする。
>   * 所詮、掃除しても、またすぐに汚れる。

Comment: Ok, so 「どうせ、彼は中学生だ。大したことはできないだろう。」 carries the hidden meaning of presupposing that 中学生 does not have the ability to do 大したこと". But apologies, I do not really understand the explanation of 「所詮」. What does *"the thing being something"* mean? What is the hidden meaning of 「所詮、彼は中学生だ。大したことはできないだろう。」?

Comment: @Pacerier It is the same. There was a mistake in the previous version of the answer, particularly, I typed the word "presupposition" by mistake; I meant "proposition". Please see the new version. The difference between the two words is that 所詮 always have to be used with `A is B`, which actually indicates that it is used with `B` rather than the whole `A is B`. どうせ can be used with propositions in general, like `C`, where `C` can be in the format like `A does D`.

Comment: So is it true that the difference in nuance between 「どうせ、彼は中学生だ。大したことはできないだろう。」 and 「所詮、彼は中学生だ。大したことはできないだろう。」 is that the first (どうせ) is an opinion of the speaker and is thus "subjective", whereas the second (所詮) is "objective"? Are there other hidden nuances besides the difference in subjectivity?

Comment: @Pacerier They don't differ in that respect. 彼は中学生だ is an objective fact. That the fact leads to likeliness of 大したことはできない is a hidden opinion of the speaker whether used with どうせ or with 所詮.