# What does どうせ mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> お前{まえ}も**どうせ**暇{ひま}だろうから誘{さそ}ってやろうと思{おも}ってよ

The dictionary tells me this means either:

> Adverb
>
> 1. anyhow; in any case; at any rate; after all; at all; no matter what​
> 2. at best; at most

So which is it in this context and how would you translate the sentence? I know this is something like "I figured you'd be free so I thought I'd invite you" but I'm not sure about the nuance introduced by どうせ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definitions you gave, I'd say "anyhow" or "in any case" fits this particular usage best. Personally, I think of どうせ as "anyway" as well.

I would translate it as:

> I thought I'd invite you since you're probably free *anyway*.

You might also want to see [this related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5899/how-to-decide-to-use-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9B-or-%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93).

Answer (score -1):

> お前も**どうせ**暇だろうから誘ってやろうと思ってよ

上記の文章の「どうせ」は次の意味です。
1. anyhow; in any case; at any rate; after all; at all; no matter what​

<del>2.at best; at most

の意味での用例は次のような場合です

どうせ一所懸命勉強しても東大には合格しないよ。

どうせ助からない命だ。ベッドにごろごろしていても仕方がない。冥途の土産にでも富士山に登ろうか。

note:「冥途の土産」is a set phrase that means "pleasant memory to take to the afterlife"</del>

---

## EDIT

jisho.org には質問者が示したように、確かに「どうせ」の定義が次のように記載されています。

> **どうせ**
>   Adverb
>   1. anyhow; in any case; at any rate; after all; at all; no matter what
>   2. at best; at most

しかし、以下に示す３つの辞書の定義によると、jisho.org に記載されている２番目の意味を「どうせ」は持っていないように推察できます。

> [**デジタル大辞泉の解説**](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9B-580712)
>   どう‐せ
>   ［副］《副詞「どう」＋動詞「す」の命令形「せよ」の音変化から》
>   １ 経過がどうであろうと、結果は明らかだと認める気持ちを表す語。**いずれにせよ**。**結局は**。  「どうせ勝つんだ、気楽にやろう」「どうせやるなら、はでにやろう」
>   ２ あきらめや、すてばちな気持ちを表す語。**所詮(しょせん)**。「どうせ私は下っ端(ぱ)ですよ」
>
> [**大辞林 第三版の解説**](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9B-580712)
>   どうせ
>   （ 副 ）
>   〔副詞「どう」に動詞「す」の命令形「せよ」の転である「せ」が付いたもの〕
>   ①
>   ある状態や結果を、初めから定まったものとして認める気持ちを表す。**いずれにしても**。**しょせん**。 「 －負けるにきまってる」 「 －ろくな物は作れないだろう」 〔多く、投げやりなあきらめや、軽蔑の気持ちを込めて使う〕
>   ②
>   ある事態を受け入れるしかないのなら、むしろその機会を積極的に利用しようとするさま。**いっそ**。 「 －作るならいいものを作ろう」 「 －なら三人分作ろう」 「 －のことだから、頂上まで行ってみよう」
>
> **広辞苑　第四版**
>   〘副詞〙（断定的な気持または投げやりな気持を伴う）どのようにしたところで、**いずれにしても**、つまりは。**所詮**。「どうせ二人はこの世では花の咲かない枯れ芒（すすき）」

jisho.org を除く３つの辞書を概括的に見ると、「どうせ」の意味は、以下のＡ、Ｂで示す２つに分類でき、更に、Ａは、のちほど用例で示すようにＡ-１とＡ-２に細分化できます。
いずれにせよ、「どうせ」には、jisho.orgの２番目の定義は含まれないように思います。

> A: ある状態や結果を、初めから定まったものとして認める気持ちを表す副詞。多くの場合、あきらめや、軽蔑の気持ちを伴って使う
>   *It is an adverb that expresses a feeling of recognizing a certain state or result as being fixed from the beginning. In many cases, it is used accompanying feelings of giving up or contempt.*
>
> B: ある事態を受け入れるしかないのなら、むしろその機会を積極的に利用しようとする様子を表す副詞。
>   An adverb that expresses "If we have no choice but to accept a situation, we would rather actively use that opportunity."

「どうせ」の持っている意味を別の言葉に言い換えると、概ね次の３つになります。

- 所詮{しょせん｝： after all, anyway
- 結局は： after all; in the end
- いっそ： rather; sooner; preferably, or better yet

日本語コーパスである「[少納言](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/)」や上記辞書の用例を上記３つの言い換えた言葉で分類すると以下のようになります。

#### A-1「所詮」に言い換えられる用例

> - **どうせ**私は下っ端(ぱ)ですよ。
> - **どうせ**そんなことだろうと思ったよ。
> - 人がいたにしても、**どうせ**死人ばかりである。
> - **どうせ**僕なんて… **どうせ**！
> - 「いいんだよ。富美子さん。**どうせ**寺の食事。たいしたものは出ませんよ。」

#### A-2「結局は」に言い換えられる用例

> - **どうせ**負けるに決まってる。
> - **どうせ**勝つんだ、気楽にやろう。
> - あの人は、**どうせ**死ぬのだ。
> - **どうせ**ろくな物は作れないだろう。
> - きっとどこかで、**どうせ**辞｛や｝めるんだという気持ちが出てきます。
> - **どうせ**、わたしよりあの負け犬のことのほうが好きなんでしょ。

#### B「いっそ」に言い換えられる用例

> - **どうせ**作る**なら**いいものを作ろう。
> - **どうせ** **なら**三人分作ろう。
> - **どうせ**やる**なら**、はでにやろう
> - **どうせ**着る**なら**、よりよく見えたい、よりよい気分で過ごしたい。
> - **どうせ** **なら**今から風になってみよう。
> - **どうせ**行く**なら**北太平洋最大のアカウミガメ産卵地、永田の浜に海がめを見に行くのもいいと思う。
> - **どうせ**受ける**なら**、偏差値の高いところを受けておこうと思ったが、受験勉強はほとんど...

**上記用例を見ますと、次のような特徴が見つかります。**

- A-2「結局は」に言い換えられる用例の文は、「どうせ + 動詞」の形で成り立つ。
- B「いっそ」に言い換えられる用例の文は、「どうせ + （動詞） + なら」の形で成り立つ。

Comment: `2. at best; at most 「どうせ一所懸命勉強しても東大には合格しないよ。」「どうせ助からない命だ。...」` ← 「せいぜい一所懸命勉強しても東大には合格しないよ。」「せいぜい助からない命だ。」って言い換えられますかね・・・？ [プログレッシブ和英](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/53253/meaning/m0u/どうせ/)を見ると、「どうせ治らない病気だ」は、#2の「〔せいぜい〕」(at most/at best など)のほうではなく、#1の「〔いずれにせよ〕anyhow; 〔結局〕after all」のほうに分類されてるんですけど・・

Comment: @Chocolate: ご指摘ありがとうございます。使用例等、もう少し調べてみます。